# Python sed regex matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sed

I am trying to use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in my Python script to remove some String.

The `sed` command I used is (on Linux):

`echo "helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f" | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$//' | sed 's/-[0-9]\{10\}$//' | sed 's/-[a-z0-9]\{8,10\}$//'`

Which would output `helloworld`.

Now, with Python, I tried to do this for the first `sed` group:

`newstring = re.sub(r'(s/-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$//)', r'\1', 'helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f')`

But it only outputs the copy, which is `helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f`

How can I perform such `sed` command ?

Edit:

My question is not about my regex expression. The inputs String are more complex than the one I presented as an example. Question is about how to prorperly use re.sub() with the regex I used :)

Comment: Are you trying to remove the last two hyphen-separated chunks? Try `re.sub(r'(?:-[^-]*){2}$', '', s)`. sed `s/-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$//` command is translated as `re.sub(r'-[a-z0-9]{5}$', '', s)`

Comment: Why don't use just search for everything before the first `-`? Else please explain when and where to split.

Comment: Take out `s/` and `//`, those are not part of the regex.

Comment: My question is not about my regex expression. The inputs String are more complexed than the one I presented as an example. 
Question is about how to prorperly use `re.sub()` with the regex I used :)

Comment: @TomZych Still gives me a copy of my inputs: 
`newstring = re.sub('-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$', '', 'helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` `s/-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$//` command is translated as `re.sub(r'-[a-z0-9]{5}$', '', s)`.

Note:

- BRE POSIX interval quantifier is written without escapes, `\{5\}` => `{5}`
- `s/<pattern>/<repl>/` means *replace `<pattern>` with `<repl>`*, and is equal to `re.sub('<pattern>', '<repl>', s, 1)` (as there is no `g` modifier in the sed command, `1` is passed to `re.sub` to only replace one, first, occurrence).

Modifiers are passed as options, or *flags*, in the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), e.g. `re.sub(r'-[a-z0-9]{5}$', '', s, flags=re.I)` (`re.I` is a case insensitive modifier). Mind there is no need using `g` modifier as `re.sub` replaces all occurrences by default.

You can learn more about Python regex syntax in the [Python `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Just FYI, you may omit `1` count argument to `re.sub` when translating `s/-[a-z0-9]\{5\}$//` command, because `$` will only make the regex match once at the end of the string. If you plan to actually replace first occurrences, always pass `1` as the count (third) argument to `re.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression does not match what you're trying to do.

Actualy your code is replacing a 5 char long alpha-numric char string that starts by an hyphen by the first match in 'helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f' (or something like this).

This case can not occur since your string does not begin by an hyphen.

If  I'm correct you want to remplace by an empty string any 5 char or 8 chars long lowercase alpha-numeric string that starts with an hyphen.

This could be achieved with this code:

Code

```
newstring = re.sub("(-[a-z0-9]{8})?(-[a-z0-9]{5})?", '', 'helloworld-5b5cf484-g582f')
```

Result

```
print newstring
helloworld
```

Here are pointers to re module doc:

1. python2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
2. python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html